# IBM Cloud Watson Assistant: How to get the ID of a workspace

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I made a chatbot using IBM Cloud Watson Assistant and I need to use it in my Android applications. This my `config.xml` code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Watson Conversation Service Credentials -->
    <string name="workspace_id">???</string>
    <string name="conversation_username">2m5tAP3W_ELNzcKlc4B5mRN6R-QXtF1C9zS22XzYXYbA</string>
    <string name="conversation_password">2m5tAP3W_ELNzcKlc4B5mRN6R-QXtF1C9zS22XzYXYbA</string>

    <!--Watson Speech-To-Text Service Credentials-->
    <string name="STT_username">yP4_u_mm3mhVNn9zcgIMFakfbcUO2Q4L5cxbLhYpn8WN</string>
    <string name="STT_password">yP4_u_mm3mhVNn9zcgIMFakfbcUO2Q4L5cxbLhYpn8WN</string>

    <!--Watson Text-To-Speech Service Credentials-->
    <string name="TTS_username">-t1Rljl4Mu1pdno09T2OXeMnQOyPPBgrEDieZSwsVzJX</string>
    <string name="TTS_password">-t1Rljl4Mu1pdno09T2OXeMnQOyPPBgrEDieZSwsVzJX</string>

</resources>
```

I know that the API key is used instead of the userName and password in the services. My problem is that I can't find the workspace ID of my chatbot. I searched a lot but I can't find it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, Workspaces in IBM Watson Assistant are now called **Skills**. So, once you create a Watson Assistant service (under AI in Catalog) on IBM Cloud.

- Click on Launch Tool
- Create a New Skill under Skills Tab.
- Click on the three vertical dots next to the Skill you just created
- Click **View API Details**[image]

- You should see the Workspace ID as the third entry under Skill Details.

**For Assistant ID,**

- Click on the action menu (three vertical dots) next to your Assistant under Assistants section.
- Click on **Settings** to see the Assistant settings page
- On the left pane, click on **API Details**
- Copy the Assistant ID

Update: 26-March-2021

- Workspaces are now Skills
- You will use Skill ID in-place of Workspace ID

To find the Skill ID and the API Key,

- Once you launch Watson Assistant, on the left pane click on `Skills` and follow the steps mentioned above.

Comment: For Assistant ID, click on Assistants tab, create new Assistant, add a skill (new or existing) and click on View API details to find the Assistant ID.

Comment: I can't get that for some reason - all I get is the Skill ID.

Comment: Updated my answer with the Assistant ID details

Comment: This is out of date as all of the labels have been changed and I can't seem to find an up to date explanation of how to find workspace-id or IAM APIKey

Comment: Updated my answer with more info