# How to export IBM Watson conversation history?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

> Before running the code, install [ibm-watson](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ibm-watson) &
> [ibm-cloud-sdk-core](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-cloud-sdk-core/) package and also `pip instll PyJWT==1.7.1`.

I found in [IBM document](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-logs-resources) that "For a Python script you can run to export logs and convert them to CSV format, download the [export_logs_py.py file](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/community/blob/master/watson-assistant/export_logs_py.py) from the Watson Assistant GitHub) repository."

But I don't really know where & how should I modify in order to connect my ibm skill.
There is no demo or instruction about where I can find those argument.
I only find these information in skill api details but it seems it needs more.
Do anyone have an example version about how to use the .py they provided？
(I'm a coding beginner, not really understand every lines in the .py)

[image]

The  .py shows an error after I run the file without modification：

```
runfile('C:/export_logs.py', wdir='C:/Users/admin/Downloads')
usage: export_logs.py [-h] [--logtype {ASSISTANT,WORKSPACE,DEPLOYMENT}]
                      [--language LANGUAGE] [--filetype {CSV,TSV,XLSX,JSON}]
                      [--url URL] [--version VERSION]
                      [--totalpages TOTALPAGES] [--pagelimit PAGELIMIT]
                      [--filter FILTER] [--strip STRIP]
                      apikey id filename
export_logs.py: error: the following arguments are required: apikey, id, filename
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

The conversation I want to download：
[image]

Comment: The script does not need any modification. You invoke it with parameters. If you don't provide any parameters, there should be some help

Comment: @data_henrik Thanks for your reply.
I try to run the script without modification, but it shows an error. (I add the error output  of the script in the post. )
Can you explain  what does " invoke it with parameters." means？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Workspaces in IBM Watson Assistant are now called Skills.

To understand what arguments(positional and optional) you need to pass to the Python script, run the below command

```
python export_logs_py.py -h
```

> Wherever you see workspace, you can replace it with skill.

To export the logs in the `.csv` file format, run the below command

```
python export_logs_py.py --filetype CSV --url <URL> <API_KEY> <SKILL_ID> output.csv
```

> Replace placeholders `<URL`, `<API_KEY>` and `<SKILL_ID>` with appropriate values mentioned below.

- <URL> & <API_KEY> - You can find them under the `Manage` page of your Watson Assistant service page
- <SKILL_ID> - The same as the one in the image you uploaded. Check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53272884/1432067) for more info.

For Assistant logs, add `--logtype ASSISTANT`. The default is WORKSPACE.

You can also find the logs in the UI under `Analytics` section of your Skill

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing so much details, I think I'm almost there. But after run the command, it shows another error：`Reading page 1. ERROR:root:Resource not found.` Do you know why this happen? (URL is assistant url)

Comment: It's not the assistant URL. As mentioned in my answer above, it's the URL that you find under the manage page of Watson assistant service or under `Service credentials` > Auto-generated credentials (Expand). The URL should look like `https://api.us-south.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/ff199a77-72c4-4705-xxxx-xxxxxx`

Comment: I think the input is all fine now, but the result is weird
`Reading page 1. No Logs found. :(Writing 0 records to: output.csv as file type: CSV`
I did see many conversation in the Analytics>conversation history page.

Comment: No conversation data is available for analysis. Typically, data is not available until your skill is deployed and has participated in conversations with users. See [Adding integrations to learn about deployment options.](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-integration-add) 

You can find the logs under Analytics > User conversations of your skill. Check the updated answer

Comment: Do you mean User conversations  can only be checked in the IBM skill, but cannot be download? Then what does this .py file can do？ (I have integrate the skill with preview link and I did see logs in the page you mentioned as I update in my question post)

Comment: Along with the `.py` file, you can also see the logs in the UI. If you are seeing the logs in the UI, you should be able to download the SAME logs with the script. Did you run the pythong script after seeing the logs in the UI?

Comment: Yes,  I  run the script after seeing the logs in the UI

Comment: Actually, I don't see output.csv either (I think it should be in the same directory as the ,py ?)

Comment: Yes. It should be in the same directory as the `.py` file

Comment: Hi, I found the problem caused by  "--logtype ASSISTANT". After I delete this everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the script reported an error and said that you have to provide the **apikey**, the **id** and the (presumably output) **filename** as parameters. It also showed that additional parameters can be specified.

```
usage: export_logs.py [-h] [--logtype {ASSISTANT,WORKSPACE,DEPLOYMENT}]
                      [--language LANGUAGE] [--filetype {CSV,TSV,XLSX,JSON}]
                      [--url URL] [--version VERSION]
                      [--totalpages TOTALPAGES] [--pagelimit PAGELIMIT]
                      [--filter FILTER] [--strip STRIP]
                      apikey id filename
```

Your next step could be now to invoke the script again, but provide an API key for Watson Assistant, the skill ID and a filename as additional paramaters. Next, I would try to something like, e.g., trying out to specify the output type:

```
export_logs.py --filetype CSV myapikey skillID output.csv
```

I am not the author of that script, but that is how I would approach it if I wanted to use it

Comment: Thanks for your generous, you help me with a lot of watson problems.